# summing columns from different dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have 3 DataFrames, all with over 100 rows and 1000 columns. I am trying to combine all these DataFrames into one in such a way that common columns from each DataFrame are summed up. I understand there is a method of summation called "pd.DataFrame.sum()", but remember, I have over 1000 columns and I can not add each common column manually. I am attaching sample DataFrames and the result I want. Help will be appreciated.

```
#Sample DataFrames.
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,1,0],'c':[1,3,5]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,0],'b':[2,1,4],'c':[1,0,2],'d':[2,2,2]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'c':[1,3,5], 'x':[2,3,4]})



     #Result.
df_total = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,5,6],'b':[4,2,4],'c':[3,6,12],'d':[2,2,2], 'x':[2,3,4]})
df_total
        a   b   c   d   x
    0   3   4   3   2   2
    1   5   2   6   2   3
    2   6   4   12  2   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `pd.concat` then `sum`

```
out = pd.concat([df_1,df_2,df_3],axis=1).sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[7]: 
   a  b   c  d  x
0  3  4   3  2  2
1  5  2   6  2  3
2  6  4  12  2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `add` with `fill_value=0`:

```
 df_1.add(df_2, fill_value=0).add(df_3, fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c  d  x
0  3  4   3  2  2
1  5  2   6  2  3
2  6  4  12  2  4
```

*Note:* pandas intrinsically aligns most operations along indexes (index and column headers).